# How to programmatically set the value of a custom field of type checkbox?

Tags: plugin, custom-field, plugin-events

In articles, I have created a series of custom fields, including two date fields and a checkboxes field. Now, through a plugin in the `onContentBeforeSave` event I need to verify that if date 1 is less than date 2 then set the value of the checkbox field. For this I try the following

```
<?php

defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

class plgContentAlertcustomfieldhandler extends JPlugin
{
    public function onContentBeforeSave($context, &$article, $isNew, $data)
    {
        if ($context === 'com_content.article') {
            $date1 = strtotime($data['com_fields']['date1']);
            $date2 = strtotime($data['com_fields']['date2']);

            if ($date1 < $date2) {
                $data['com_fields']['alert'][0] = 'alert';
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I try to set the value in this line:

```
$data['com_fields']['alert'][0] = 'alert';
```

This custom field has only one checkbox, defined with the name Alert and with the value alert.

**Update 1:**

I am trying `$data['com_fields']['alert'] = true;` but I am getting the same result.

**Update 2:**

If I manually set a value to the checkbox, debugging I can verify that the value assigned to alert in `$data` is

```
array (
   0 => 'alert',
)
```

I try to apply this same value programmatically as follows

```
$data['com_fields']['alert'] = ['alert'];
```

But the value is not persisted, at the end of the process of saving and refreshing the view the checkbox remains unchecked

**Update 3**

Following the process of saving through debugging I identify that if I programmatically assign the value to the custom field through `$data ['com_fields']['alert'] = ['alert'];` when arriving to the `save` method in `libraries/src/MVC/Model/AdminModel.php` in the argument `$data` the value of `alert` is `false`, while if I set a value manually when arriving at this method in`$data` the value of the `alert` field is `[0 => 'alert']` and consequently the value of the checkbox is assigned.

**Update 4**

The typo error pointed out by alexandreelise is now repaired. The problem still persists.

**Update 5**

Using debug I managed to identify that it doesn't matter which field within `$ data['com_fields']` I modify in the `onContentBeforeSave` event once it delegates to the `trigger` method of the `JEventDispatcher` class located at `libraries/joomla/event/dispatcher.php` the argument `$args` that includes in the index 3 the data to be persisted including those of `com_fields` retain the values set by the user even if they have been programmatically modified as in the example I described. Eventually this data is passed to `libraries/src/MVC/Model/AdminModel.php` in the `save` method that has the argument `$data` the data to be inserted preserves the values set by the user. Right now I think that maybe the solution is to try to modify these values in another event maybe before `onContentBeforeSave`. Thanks again for any ideas

I appreciate your advice

Comment: Hi, Is there a particular reason why you would use checkboxes for only one checkbox? Maybe you should use a radio button for that. Just my 2 cents piece of advise.

Comment: for now it's the requirement that I have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you needed to use `onContentAfterSave` rather then `onContentBeforeSave` and use the `FieldsHelper` in conjuction with the `FieldsModelField`.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

class plgContentAlertcustomfieldhandler extends JPlugin
{
   public function onContentAfterSave($context, &$article, $isNew)
   {

    if ($context === 'com_content.article') {
        $custom_fields = FieldsHelper::getFields($context, $article, true);
        $custom_fields_by_name = \Joomla\Utilities\ArrayHelper::pivot($custom_fields, 'name');

        $date1 = strtotime($custom_fields_by_name['date1']->value);
        $date2 = strtotime($custom_fields_by_name['date2']->value);

        if ($date1 < $date2) {
            //define the value you want to assign
            $your_custom_field_value = 'alert';

            JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/models');
            /**
             * @var FieldsModelField $model_field
             */
            $model_field = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Field', 'FieldsModel', ['ignore_request' => true]);

            //set the value using field model instead to make change permanent in db
            $model_field->setFieldValue(
                $custom_fields_by_name['alert']->id,
                $article->id,
                $your_custom_field_value
            );
        }
    }

     return true;
     }
  }
```

UPDATE:

Second version of the code toggling on and off the checkbox when your requirement is not met.

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

class plgContentAlertcustomfieldhandler extends JPlugin
{
    public function onContentAfterSave($context, &$article, $isNew)
    {

    if ($context === 'com_content.article') {
        $custom_fields = FieldsHelper::getFields($context, $article, true);
        $custom_fields_by_name = \Joomla\Utilities\ArrayHelper::pivot($custom_fields, 'name');

        $date1 = strtotime($custom_fields_by_name['date1']->value);
        $date2 = strtotime($custom_fields_by_name['date2']->value);

        $your_custom_field_value = '';
        if ($date1 < $date2) {
            //define the value you want to assign
            $your_custom_field_value = 'alert';
        }
        JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/models');
        /**
         * @var FieldsModelField $model_field
         */
        $model_field = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Field', 'FieldsModel', ['ignore_request' => true]);

        //set the value using field model instead to make change permanent in db
        $model_field->setFieldValue(
            $custom_fields_by_name['alert']->id,
            $article->id,
            $your_custom_field_value
        );
      }

      return true;
     }
 }
```